# Incorrect Content-Type for Soap Version. Got application/soap+xml but expected text/xml (Spring-Boot)

Tags: java, soap, spring-boot, java-8, spring-ws

I have a spring-boot application where i need to send a SOAP-Message (Version 1.2) and receive the reply. Timeout should be 30 seconds;

Below is my class;

```
@Component
public class SettingsSenderClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

@Autowired
private DatabaseService databaseService;

@Autowired
public void setHttpComponentsMessageSender(HttpComponentsMessageSenderWithTimeout messageSenderWithTimeout) {
    WebServiceTemplate template = getWebServiceTemplate();
    template.setMessageSender(messageSenderWithTimeout);
  //template.setMessageFactory(messageFactory());
}

//@Bean(name = "webServiceTemplate")
//public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {
    //WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    //webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(httpComponentsMessageSender());
    //webServiceTemplate.setMessageFactory(messageFactory());
    //return webServiceTemplate;
//}

@Bean
public SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
    SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
    messageFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_12);
    return messageFactory;
}

public void sendSettings() {
    List<SettingsDetails> settingsDetails = databaseService.getSettingsDetailBySettingsID();
    if (!settingsDetails.isEmpty()) {
        //Build the "SettingsRequest" SOAP Message From WSDL Generated Classes For Each Record
        settingsDetails.stream().forEachOrdered((settingsDetail) -> {
            try {
                //Build SettingsDetail Request
                SettingsDetailRequest request = new SettingsDetailRequest();
                request.setDetail1(settingsDetail.getSettingsDetail1());
                request.setDetail2(settingsDetail.getSettingsDetail2());

                //Log The URL To Send
                String settingURL = settingsDetail.getSettingsURL();
                LogService.info(this.getClass().getName(),"Sending Message on URL: " + deviceURL);

                JAXBElement<SettingsDetailResponse> jaxbElementResponse = (JAXBElement<SettingsDetailResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate()
                        .marshalSendAndReceive(settingURL,
                                new ObjectFactory().createSettingsDetailRequest(request), (WebServiceMessage message) -> {

                            SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
                            SoapHeaderElement id = soapMessage.getSoapHeader().addHeaderElement(new QName(namespaceUrl, localpart, "sp"));
                            id.setText(settingsDetail.getSettingName());
                        });

                SettingsDetailResponse response = jaxbElementResponse.getValue();

                //Get The Response Status
                String responseStatus = response.getStatus().value();
                //Wait 1 Second in each loop
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    LogService.error(this.getClass().getName(), "Intrp Error");
                    LogService.error(this.getClass().getName(), ex);
                }
            } catch (WebServiceIOException ex) {
                LogService.error(this.getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage());
                //Catch The Timeout Exception Here (How??? //TODO)
                LogService.error(this.getClass().getName(), ex);
            }
        });
    } else {
        LogService.info(this.getClass().getName(), "No Records Found To Send Settings SOAP Message(s)");
    }
 }
}
```

I have the `messageFactory` bean configured to use `SoapVersion.SOAP_12`.
But still i get the Error:

```
[Exception: ]org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to internalize message; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to internalize message
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:216)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:611)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
        at com.myapp.ws.outgoing.SettingsSenderJobClient.lambda$sendSettings$1(SettingsSenderJobClient.java:107)
        at com.myapp.ws.outgoing.SettingsSenderJobClient$$Lambda$8/1215330412.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(Unknown Source)
        at com.myapp.ws.outgoing.SettingsSenderJobClient.sendSettings(SettingsSenderJobClient.java:71)
        at com.tingco.myapp.SettingsSenderJob.execute(SettingsSenderJob.java:24)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to internalize message
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.init(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.createMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:188)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPVersionMismatchException: Cannot create message: incorrect content-type for SOAP version. Got: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="/ChangeConfiguration" Expected: text/xml
        ... 18 more
```

**UPDATE**

I removed the `SaajSoapMessageFactory` and did like below which is working. What is difference here? Arn't they both `messageFactories`?

```
@Bean
public WebServiceMessageFactory webServiceMessageFactory() throws SOAPException {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
    WebServiceMessageFactory webMessageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(messageFactory);
    return webMessageFactory;
}

@Autowired
public void setHttpComponentsMessageSender(HttpComponentsMessageSenderWithTimeout messageSenderWithTimeout) throws SOAPException {
    WebServiceTemplate template = getWebServiceTemplate();
    template.setMessageSender(messageSenderWithTimeout);
    template.setMessageFactory(webServiceMessageFactory());
}
```

If i do the same with `SaajSoapMessageFactory`, i get `nullpointer exception`.

Comment: You have it configured and next happily ignore it. You are only configuring it you aren't wiring it up to anything else, hence it is pretty much useless.

Comment: I will post a answer to this. can you please tell me what is the difference?

Comment: You haven't removed anything you still have the `SaajSoapMessageFactory` but you are now actually using it.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Yes i see now. Got it. Thank You. Can you please post an answer so i can accept and maybe it will be helpful to someone in future. :)